# Moved Website Directory - User File Uploads broken

Tags: php, wordpress, file-upload, woocommerce, gravity-forms-plugin

I just moved my website from a subdomain to the main domain (public_html) in order to activate a SSL certificate. In the process the file uploader I have on the website's form broke and now displays URLs to the images but the images have not been uploaded and a "not found page" is returned when one of these links are clicked. A week ago before I moved the site, the images were being uploaded to the appropriate folder and were displayed when their urls were clicked.

I would appreciate any help as to how to fix this problem. I am using Gravity Forms File Uploader with WooCommerce.

Thank you!

Comment: Change the URLs to the new URLs for those images?

Comment: Thanks for responding. The domain never changed for the site, it just got moved within the server location. I wouldn't have thought that this would break this feature but for whatever reason the images are no longer being uploaded.

Comment: Am I understanding that the problem is not existing images but new images being uploaded via the form?

Comment: Yes. Prior to  moving the site up a directory to public_html and activating the SSL, all images selected to be uploaded were actually placed in a folder on the server. Now, a url appears on the checkout page for the "uploaded" images but they are never transferred to the server.

Comment: Has adding the SSL and the https to the url effected file uploads?

Comment: Look in your browser's developer console. See why the images are failing to load. 404? Mixed content?

Comment: The images aren't loading because they aren't being uploaded even though they were before I moved the site's directory and activated the SSL certificate.